# Formula Field to show under Grand Total as well as sub-sections

Tags: reporting

[image]

I've had to create duplicate formula fields to serve the purpose because it doesn't show the calculation for individual categories as well as for grand total section to the right. I find this redundant and want to merge them. How can I do this so it shows me the data throughout?

Comment: Weird. Can you describe / share the screenshot of your formula definition? I'm especially wondering about the ["at all summary levels"](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/images/dev_guides/appx_dev/images/adg_reports_summary_formula.jpg) etc. (img taken from http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/Content/adg_reports_summary_fields_try_it_out.htm)

Comment: The Total fields are:
At specific row/column (A) Opportunity Owner (B) Column Grand Summary
The normal fields are:
At specific row/column (A) Opportunity Owner (B) Opportunity Record Type